# Como obtener una segunda clase de una misma etiqueta

Tags: javascript, jquery

Cómo puedo obtener una segunda clase de una etiqueta mediante un click

Esta es la etiqueta con dos clases necesito obtener la segunda

```
<span class="naranja manzana">Click</span>
```

intenté con `attr` de esta forma

```
$(".naranja").click(function(){

   var 2daClase = $(this).attr("class",2);

    alert(2daClase )


})
```

resultado `[object Object]`

resultado esperado **"manzana"**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puede utilizar la propiedad `classList` que retorna la lista de clases, para obtener la segunda clase, se accede a la posición 1, ya que los `array` inician en la posición `0`

```js
$(".naranja").click(function(){
  var segunda = $(this).prop('classList')[1];
  console.log(segunda );
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="naranja manzana">Click</span>
<span class="naranja zandia">Click</span>
```

Comment: Gracias! esta genial

Answer (score 1):

Lo haria de esta forma obteniedo todas las clases y luego meterlas en un array

```js
$(".naranja").click(function(){
   var classes = $(this).attr("class");
   var clases = classes.split(/(\s+)/);
   // clases = ["naranja"," ", "manzana"]
   if( !(typeof clases[2] === 'undefined') ) {
     console.log(clases[2]);
   }
   
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="naranja manzana">Click</span>
```

Comment: Cuidado con el `split`, fallará si en lugar de espacios hay un tab de separación entra las clases.  3;)

Comment: cierto, y tambien si solo hay una clase en el elemento.